# ParseRequestException (@ParseRequest:newPermanentException:352) {main}

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am getting the following exception reported in my Google Analytics for Android app.

```
ParseRequestException (@ParseRequest:newPermanentException:352) {main}
```

This is the top exception with more than 4000 hits. I am worried that some users are not able to register on parse and unable to receive push notifications. Unfortunately, I don't have any other information being reported and I am unable to replicate this on any Android devices that I have.

Here is the code, where I am initializing Parse:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXX", "YYY");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Utils.sendException(appContext, e);
            }
        }
    });
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, ChatActivity.class);
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(getResources().getString(R.string.parse_default_channel), new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "Problem subscribing to the chat service. You will not be able to receive notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Utils.sendException(appContext, e);
            }
        }
    });
```

When I searched for this Exception on Google, I found only 3 results and they don't have any info. I want to know:
1. If I am doing something wrong?
2. How this may be hurting my app's users?
3. How to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone help me out here!